# Will this power supply fit my LiPO charger?

Tags: power-supply, power, battery-charging, remote-control

I just got my brand new LiPO battery charger. It is require 12 volt pover supply.
I saw people are using car battery, pc power supply to this charger 12 V. but i'm not sure  about current it is require.

[image: $ 4 button LiPO battery charger / balancer]

**Here is spec:**

```
Operating voltage range: 10.0~18.0Volt
Circuit power: max.50W for charging, max.5W for discharging
Charge current range: 0.1~5.0A
Discharge current range: 0.1~1.0A
Current drain for balancing Li-po: 300mAh/cell
NiCd/ NiMH battery cell count: 1~15cells
Lithium battery cell count: 1~6Series
Pb battery voltage: 2 to 20V
Dimension: 135×100×40mm
```

Will it be ok if i use for power supply  **plug in transformer** which outputs `12 VDC, 800mA`?

[image]
[image]

Dont wanna damage any of them.

Comment: To get close to the performance of the charger, you'll need a 5 A power supply. The calculation is simple P=V*I. Here P=50 W and I've used V=12 V and added a bit of safety margin.

Comment: Consumer electronics support is off topic. I realize you are working hard to find a power supply for your unit you purchased but there is no design here. The focus of this is picking a cheap power supply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plugin transformer outputs 800mA, your charger has 50W output max at 12V.

50W / 12V = 4.17A

Transformer you have is too weak for this. PC PSUs have output somewhere in range of 10A on 12V rail, that's why they can be used.

Comment: Will power supply (Transformer) burn if i use them together?

Comment: it *could* burn, it all depends on a design of charger.

Comment: @Pol: take no chances and look for a PC PSU. Virtually any PSU will do the job, so you will be able to get one for free if you look in the right places. There are also a lot of tutorials on the web how to run a PSU without a mainboard attached.

Comment: What about notebook power supply? Is it to powerful  for this charger? It shows 10.0~18.0Volt operating voltage range. I thing notebook charger would do the job. How go think?

Comment: It's all in what maximum current your power source can deliver, it has to be greater than what your charger uses

Comment: What if it is deliver less. Will it work with less performance?

Comment: it depends on the charger, if it traks available power source, it might work with less performance, otherwise, it will melt your power supply.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tested yesterday.  I't is working perfectly with 12 VDC, 0.8 A power supply. Actually i have 2 more one is 12 VDC, 2 A and another one is 12 VDC, 1.5 A. But they have different input plug. So i could not test them.

Comment: No, it's not working perfectly.  Sooner or later you are going to damage something or start a fire.  If you're extremely lucky, you're just limited to about 10 watts of power for charging instead of the 50 watts the charger can output.  This is VERY DANGEROUS.

Comment: Id does not even heat the power supply.

Comment: You're still playing with fire.  You said specifically "dont want to damage any of them", several people have said you must have a larger supply and given you reasons, you ignored it and did it anyway, and are on borrowed time for one of these devices.

Comment: I'm steel looking for something more appropriate.

Comment: I think this one would fit me  12V DC 4A 4000mA DC Power Supply Adapter 100V - 240V AC with Power Cord. Found on ebay.

Comment: Spend literally a dollar more and find one that's a minimum of 5A.  10A would be safest.

Comment: As I understand charger will suck the current it needed? Even if power supply provide a lot more than charger require. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, power supplies are rated by the maximum they can provide, and devices are rated by the maximum they will draw.  Make sure "can provide" is larger than "will draw".

Comment: @insta: What is going to be if i put more voltage. From my laptop. It is 19 V and 4000 mA? Or i have an other one: 15 V 6000 mA. Will this kill my charger if voltage is higher than required?